# Reset X display configuration?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I should know better, but I was installing updated NVidia drivers for my laptop and have gotten things so messed up that X will not start properly.  Using Kubuntu 21.04.  The laptop is an Eluktronics RP-17 with an AMD Ryzen 7 4800H processor with graphics (used for the laptop display) and an NVidia 2060 that drives the monitor.  I've tried a number of things with no success - removing and reinstalling both the AMDGPU and Nvidia-driver-470 packages, but I'm not having any success getting X to start properly. I've tried going back to the 460 driver, updating AMDGPU, but my guess is that my Xconfigs are so messed up that I need to revert to scratch.    I've tried ./X -configure but it throws an error:
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
Configuration failed.

Any assistance completely resetting the X display configuration would be appreciated.

Comment: In the `/etc/X11/` folder you should have backups of the `xorg.conf` file in there for any driver updates, etc.  You can try copying the oldest one back as `xorg.conf`.

Comment: I tried that, but there weren't any xorg.conf files present :(

Comment: You can try creating a new one using `sudo nvidia-xconfig`